# java.io.NotSerializableException: Graph is unexpectedly null when DStream is being serialized

Tags: java, spark-streaming

I am new in **spark** streaming programming please someone explain for me what is the problem 
I thing that that i iterate a null structure but i have a producer class which works normally
my source code :

```
public class Main3 implements java.io.Serializable {
     public static JavaDStream<Double> pr;
    public  void consumer() throws Exception{


    // Configure Spark to connect to Kafka running on local machine
    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
    kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"group1");
    kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"latest");
    kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG,true);



    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("testing");
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("SparkKafka10WordCount");
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(30));
    final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> receiver=
            KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                    ConsumerStrategies.<String,String>Subscribe(topics,kafkaParams));
 JavaDStream<String> stream = receiver.map(new Function<ConsumerRecord<String,String>, String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> kafkaRecord) throws Exception {
            return kafkaRecord.value();
        }
    });


stream.foreachRDD( x->x.saveAsTextFile("/home/khouloud/Desktop/exemple/b")); //that does no do any thing 
   stream.foreachRDD( x-> {
        x.collect().stream().forEach(n-> System.out.println("item of list: "+n));
    }); // also this i see any thing in the console

    stream.foreachRDD( rdd -> {
        if (rdd.isEmpty()) System.out.println("its empty"); }); //nothing`


JavaPairDStream<Integer, List<Double>> points= stream.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, Integer, List<Double>>(){
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer, List<Double>> call(String x) throws Exception {
            String[]  item = x.split(" ");
            List<Double> l = new ArrayList<Double>();
            for (int i= 1 ; i < item.length ; i++)
            {

                l.add(new Double(item[i]));
            }
            return new Tuple2<>(new Integer(item[0]), l);
        }}
    );`
```

Error -

> `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:340)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:156)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2294)     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(DStream.scala:547)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(DStream.scala:547)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.withScope(StreamingContext.scala:265)
>     at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.map(DStream.scala:546)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$class.mapToPair(JavaDStreamLike.scala:163)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.AbstractJavaDStreamLike.mapToPair(JavaDStreamLike.scala:42)
>     at Min.calculDegSim(Min.java:43)    at SkyRule.execute(SkyRule.java:34)
>     at Main3.consumer(Main3.java:159)   at
>   Executer$2.run(Executer.java:27)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: Graph is unexpectedly null when
>   DStream is being serialized. Serialization stack:
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:337)

Comment: Do you have an exception stack trace? Also, you will need to mention line numbers in your code so anyone trying to answer can correlate.

Comment: points.mapToPair(x->{
 this cause the execption i think

Comment: How are you executing this program?

Comment: And please post working code. I tried using your code to debug but it is very badly organized. I am getting lot of compiler issues.

Comment: Also provide the spark version  and kafka version you are using.

Comment: i have many class (kafka producer , the executor ..) and this the consumer one

Comment: i use kafka 10 spark 2.2.1 anad spark streaming 2.2.1